# Shell variable issue when trying to mkdir

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

Any ideas what is wrong with this code?

```
CLIENT_BUILD_DIR="~/Desktop/TempDir/"

if [ ! -d $CLIENT_BUILD_DIR ]
then
   {
      mkdir $CLIENT_BUILD_DIR
   }
fi
```

I get the error:  mkdir: ~/Desktop: No such file or directory.

Obviously the directory is there and the script works if I replace the variable with ~/Desktop/TempDir/

Comment: One more tip, you can simplify the code to `[ -d $CLIENT_BUILD_DIR ] || mkdir $CLIENT_BUILD_DIR` and preferably add `|| echo "Error trying to create dir: $CLIENT_BUILD_DIR"` :)

Comment: Why not simply use `mkdir -p`? You don't have to check `if not exist then create`.

Comment: When you run into these sorts of problems (re: shell metacharacters like `~` and whether or not they expand inside strings), I recommend testing with `echo` until you understand what's going on. Compare the output of each of these—`echo ~/Desktop; echo ~"/Desktop"; echo ~/"Desktop"; echo "~/Desktop"`—and you'll see that the expansion of `~/` only happens when it's **not** inside a quoted string.

Comment: You get the error ` mkdir: ~/Desktop: No such file or directory` because `mkdir` without `-p` doesn't create intermediate directories, and when you hide the tilde inside quotes, it's not expanded as normal. Instead, it's treated as a literal `~`. There's no directory named `~` in the current working directory, and there's no directory `Desktop` inside _that_, hence the error. If you'd blindly used `mkdir -p` without the understanding, you'd have ended up with a directory named `~`, which is a tragic accident waiting to happen when you go to try and delete that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The quotes prevent the expansion of ~.

Use:

```
CLIENT_BUILD_DIR=~/Desktop/TempDir/

if [ ! -d "$CLIENT_BUILD_DIR" ]
then mkdir "$CLIENT_BUILD_DIR"
fi
```

Answer (score 16):

The `~` character is not reinterpret when used in a variable.

You can use `CLIENT_BUILD_DIR="$HOME/Desktop/TempDir/"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir ${CLIENT_BUILD_DIR}` will do. No directory will be created if it already exists.